# Calculate Business Hours in Different Timezones Relative to User's Location

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm building a location based app that lets users find nearby restaurants and determine if they are open or closed

Users also have the ability to search restaurants across the globe. The app will 
 inform them if the restaurants found are open or closed relative to the user's timezone

I store the hours as an object in the standard Date format

```
{
  openTime: Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
  closeTime: Thu Jan 01 1970 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
}
```

To determine if a business is open or not, I'm running the following calculation

```
let openTime = moment(hours.open_time).format('HH:mm');
let closeTime = moment(hours.close_time).format('HH:mm');
let currentTime = moment().format('HH:mm');
// output format: Open: 09:00 | Close: 20:00 | Current: 19:30)

let isOpen = currentTime >= openTime && currentTime < closeTime ? true : false;
```

(This check may be flawed for restaurants open past midnight)

How should I be performing this calculation for different timezones? I have [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) ready to go, but I haven't figured out the logic of it yet

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I'm thinking a UTC offset might be needed? I'm just totally unsure at this point

Comment: If you want to show, to the end user, whether the location being looked at is currently open, for *their timezone, in their browser" then the open/close hours should not be stored with timezone at all.

If a store opens at 8am and closes at 5pm, store in 24hr time, openTime: 8, closeTime 17. Then in your frontend js, you work out whether *your* hour (local time, in the browser) is between 5 and 17.

Comment: I have come up with an answer, but I need to know if the date object you have is the actually close date/time or is it just the times with the epoch date?

Comment: @DavidKamer what I've provided above is exactly how I save the date (24 hour time included). Chris makes a good point that I might not even need to store the date this way if using the 24 hour format

Comment: Did you solve this, I have this need now and running into a wall.